# Pass the link on blur function instead of clicking another link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to pass the link on textbox **blur** function.

**Jquery code**

```
 <a id="checkEmail" href="#" ></a> | <a id="getCandidate"></a> */* this is the link for get the profile details*/*
<script type ="text/javascript">
                $('#getCandidate').text('Get Profile') // Sets text for email.
                    .attr('href', '#');

                $("#Email").blur(function () {
                    $('#checkEmail').trigger('click');
                      //$('#checkEmail').trigger('GetCandidateDetail?validateEmail=' + $('#Email').val());

                        $('#getCandidate').text('Get Profile')
                        .attr('href', 'GetCandidateDetail?validateEmail=' + $('#Email').val());
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#checkEmail').click(function () {
                        var name = $('#Email').val();
                        var data = 'validateEmail=' + name;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "ValidateCandidate",
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);

                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
          </script>
```

**Html code**

```
 <%: Html.TextBox("Email",Model.Email, new {@title="Enter the Candidate Email Id"})%>

 <a id="checkEmail" href="#" ></a> | <a id="getCandidate"></a>
```

In the above code when I type the email id in textbox it triggers email id is registered or not. Then I give one more link **getdetails**. If I click that link then the profile will come by using the link `GetCandidateDetail?validateEmail=' + $('#Email').val())`.

But Now I want when I type the email id in textbox, if exists means it will load the link `GetCandidateDetail?validateEmail=' + $('#Email').val())`automatically otherwise false. How to do this? Help me to come out this issue?

Comment: You should put all your code in ready function. You can't use DOM elements before it's fully loaded.

Comment: k i am updating my question..please see

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Email").on('blur', function() {

        // Check mail on blur
        var email = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ValidateCandidate",
            data: {validateEmail:email},
            success: function(data) {
              // handle your response

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

function verify() {

```
                        var name = $('#Email').val();
                        var data = 'validateEmail=' + name;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "ValidateCandidate",
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);


                        return false;
                    });
                }

$("#Email").blur(function(){verify();)
$("#checkEmail").click(function(){verify()})
```

thats it !!